# Saving User Data to Database From Facebook API

Tags: php, facebook, api

I am requesting `Facebook Users` `tagged_places` with the `FB API V-4`.

Once I have the data I am doing

```
<?php  echo '<pre>' . print_r( $graphObject, 1 ) . '</pre>'; ?>
```

The data looks like thic when its printed on the screen

```
[data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 111111111111111
                            [created_time] => 1905-01-01T08:00:00+0000
                            [place] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [id] => 1111111111111
                                    [location] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [latitude] => 36.1313
                                            [longitude] => -95.9373
                                        )

                                    [name] => Tulsa, Oklahoma
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 11111111111
                            [created_time] => 2014-05-30T21:41:11+0000
                            [place] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [id] => 111111111111111
                                    [location] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [city] => Okmulgee
                                            [country] => United States
                                            [latitude] => 35.623012460758
                                            [longitude] => -95.972782756346
                                            [state] => OK
                                            [street] => 104 S Morton Ave
                                            [zip] => 74447-5022
                                        )

                                    [name] => Ike's Downtown Pub & Eatery
                                )

                        )
```

How would I save this information to a database with?

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to get each value. So if I do echo $graphObject['tagged_places']; its prints all this data out. I was assuming I needed to get each value in toa  variable. like $city $country $name etc then I could just enter it all into a database?

Comment: So if its a stdClass Object Then I would get its value like this, `echo $graphObject->{'$STDCLASS'}->{'$FIELD I'M TRYING TO GET'};` How can I tell what the name of the stdClass is?

Comment: Should work to get the id of the first location `$graphObject['data'][0]->id`

Comment: This is what I keep running in to, With countless attempts to achieve accessing any specific part the data array `Notice: Undefined index: data Notice: Trying to get property of non-objec`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you would retrieve each value you have in `tagged_places`

```
 $graphObject['tagged_places']->data->id
 $graphObject['tagged_places']->data->created_time
 $graphObject['tagged_places']->data->place->id
 $graphObject['tagged_places']->data->place->location->latitude
 $graphObject['tagged_places']->data->place->location->longitude
 $graphObject['tagged_places']->data->place->location->state
 $graphObject['tagged_places']->data->place->location->street
 $graphObject['tagged_places']->data->place->location->zip
 $graphObject['tagged_places']->data->place->name
```

This is how you would insert them into a MySQL database,

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('
    INSERT INTO this_should_be_your_table_name
    (id, created_time, place_id, latitude, longitude, state, street, zip, name)
    VALUES
    (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
');

foreach($graphObject['tagged_places']->data as $data) {
   $stmt->execute(array(
       $data->id,
       $data->created_time,
       $data->place->id,
       $data->place->location->latitude,
       $data->place->location->longitude,
       $data->place->location->state,
       $data->place->location->street,
       $data->place->location->zip,
       $data->place->name
   ));
}
```